# python 3.10 can't set proxy HTTP/HTTPS on selenium 4

Tags: python, selenium

```
selenium 4.2.0
python 3.10.4
```

Having issue while trying to set up proxy on gecko driver Firefox using python
Tried with

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

profile_path = r'C:\Users\Hodzi\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\dzwrop1t.default-release'
options=Options()
options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.type',1)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.http', '154.30.216.64')
options.set_preference('network.proxy.http_port', 8800)

service = Service()
driver = Firefox(service=service, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.whatismyip.com/")
driver.quit()
```

Output: My regular IP address

In settings I see this.

[image]

If I manually check "Also use this proxy for HTTPS!" then it works.

Is it possible to check or set this proxy through code also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a few preferences for the full proxy setup. Here's the full set that I use for setting a proxy for Firefox WebDriver (Python):

```py
options.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
options.set_preference("network.proxy.http", proxy_server)
options.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", int(proxy_port))
options.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl", proxy_server)
options.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port", int(proxy_port))
```